# Get value from combined group button and dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm very close to being able to get the value when a button is pressed OR an item from the dropdown list is selected, but I'd like my function to wait or print nothing when the user selects the `OTHER` button because this means the value will come from the dropdown

I'm also not entirely convinced the JS code I've written is the most elegant. Besides removing the `undefined` I was also hoping to get some help refactoring the code?

Any help appreciated!!

```js
var header = document.getElementById("test");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  this.className += " active";
    
  // Set results to value, unless it's other
  // then set to the value of the selected dropdown
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = $(this).attr("value")
  });
}

  $(".dropdown-item").click(function () {
         var value = $(this).attr("value");
     document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = value   
   });
```

```css
.btn-grey {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.active, .btn-secondary:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="test">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <button class="btn btn-grey active", type="button", value="NONE">NONE</button>
  <button class="btn btn-grey", type="button", value="A">A</button>
  <button class="btn btn-grey", type="button", value="B">B</button>
  <button class="btn btn-grey", type="button", value="C">C</button>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-grey dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      OTHER <span class='caret'></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#3" value="3">3</a>
      <br>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#2" value="4">4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  

<div id="results"></div>
```

Codepen also included if that's easier: https://codepen.io/mayagans/pen/dyoppZK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to check if there is a value, then replace the content..
Modified your code,

> -> With variables from `var` to `const` as the variables are read only..
>
> -> Used `let` inside for loop..
>
> -> Replaced `innerHTML` with `textContent` (Use `innerHTML` only you assign html element else if it is just text
>   then use `textContent`..

```js
const header = document.getElementById("test");

const btns = header.querySelectorAll('.btn');


for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
  current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
  this.className += " active";
    console.log();
  // Set results to value, unless it's other
  // then set to the value of the selected dropdown
    if($(this).attr("value")){
        document.getElementById("results").textContent = $(this).attr("value")
    }

  });
}

  $(".dropdown-item").click(function () {
         const value = $(this).attr("value");
     document.getElementById("results").textContent = value   
   });
```

```css
.btn-grey {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.active, .btn-secondary:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="test">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <button class="btn btn-grey active", type="button", value="NONE">NONE</button>
  <button class="btn btn-grey", type="button", value="A">A</button>
  <button class="btn btn-grey", type="button", value="B">B</button>
  <button class="btn btn-grey", type="button", value="C">C</button>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-grey dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      OTHER <span class='caret'></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#3" value="3">3</a>
      <br>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#2" value="4">4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  

<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it by using JQuery

```js
$('body').on('click', 'button[value], a.dropdown-item', function(){
  var value = $(this).attr('value');
  $('#results').html(value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="test">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <button class="btn btn-grey active" type="button" value="NONE">NONE</button>
  <button class="btn btn-grey" type="button" value="A">A</button>
  <button class="btn btn-grey" type="button" value="B">B</button>
  <button class="btn btn-grey" type="button" value="C">C</button>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-grey dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      OTHER <span class='caret'></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#3" value="3">3</a>
      <br>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#4" value="4">4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  

<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a specific class "`not-dropdown`" just for your non-dropdown items and select just them when you change your value.

See in the snippet

```js
$("#test").find(".btn").each((index1, element) => {
  const jqueryElement = $(element);
  jqueryElement.on('click', () => {

    $("#test").find(".btn").each((index2, element2) => {
      if($(element2).hasClass("active")){
        $(element2).removeClass("active");
      }
    });

    jqueryElement.addClass("active");
    $("#results").html(jqueryElement.attr("value"));

  });
});

$(".dropdown-item").click(function () {
  var value = $(this).attr("value");
  $("#results").html(value);
});
```

```css
.btn-grey {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Style the active class, and buttons on mouse-over */
.active, .btn-secondary:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="test">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <button class="btn btn-grey not-dropdown active", type="button", value="NONE">NONE</button>
  <button class="btn btn-grey not-dropdown", type="button", value="A">A</button>
  <button class="btn btn-grey not-dropdown", type="button", value="B">B</button>
  <button class="btn btn-grey not-dropdown", type="button", value="C">C</button>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-grey dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      OTHER <span class='caret'></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#3" value="3">3</a>
      <br>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#2" value="4">4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  

<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would create two callback functions: one for button clicks and one for dropdown item clicks.

Second, I would assign the clicks to two different sets of query selector results: one for buttons and one for dropdown items. When looping through the buttons, check if the class name of the current button indicates it is a dropdown item; only assign an event listener if it is not a dropdown item.

```
var buttons = header.getElementsByClassName("btn")
var dropdownItems = header.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-item")
var buttonClickCallback = function (event) { ... }
var dropdownItemClickCallback = function (event) { ... }

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  if(!button.classList.hasClass('dropdown-toggle') {
    button.addEventListener('click', buttonClickCallback)
  }
})
dropdownItems.forEach((dropdownItem) => {
  dropdownItem.addEventListener('click', dropdownItemClickCallback)
})
```